NDSolveValue + some parameters works, but ParametricNDSolveValue fails
It's most likely a syntax error but I'm currently lost in limbo. Any help would be appreciated.
I want to solve a DE with three parameters. If I give the three parameters and use NDSolveValue, this works fine. But if I use ParametricNDSolveValue and then plot the result with the same parameters, then this fails.
My code with NDSolveValue
Clear[t0,a0,qb];
c0 = 2;
tinf = 4;
tsup = 5;
k = tsup-tinf;
s = 1;
G[c_] = 1/(1 + Exp[-(c - c0*k)/s]);
g[c_] = D[G[c], c];
H[w_] = G[w] (1 - G[w]);
h[w_] = D[H[w], w];

t0 = 4.5;
qb = 2;
a0 = .2;

WR1temp = 
 NDSolveValue[{(w1''[t] - 2) G[w1[t]]/g[w1[t]] + (c0*k - w1[t]) + (w1'[t])^2/2 ==0, w1'[tinf] == tinf-c0-qb, w1'[t0] == a0}, w1, {t, tinf, t0}]

Plot[WR1temp[t], {t,tinf,t0},PlotRange -> All]
Clear[t0, a0, qb];

My code with ParametricNDSolveValue
Clear[t0,a0,qb];
c0 = 2;
tinf = 4;
tsup = 5;
k =tsup-tinf;
s = 1;
G[c_] = 1/(1 + Exp[-(c - c0*k)/s]);
g[c_] = D[G[c], c];
H[w_] = G[w] (1 - G[w]);
h[w_] = D[H[w], w];

WR1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(w1''[t] - 2) G[w1[t]]/g[w1[t]] + (c0*k - w1[t]) + (w1'[t])^2/2 == 0, w1'[tinf] == tinf-c0-qb, w1'[t0] == a0}, w1,{t,tinf,t0}, {t0, qb, a0}]

t0 = 4.5;
qb = 2;
a0 = .2;
Plot[WR1[t0,qb,a0][t], {t,tinf,t0},PlotRange -> All]

I get the following output
ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable w1^\[Prime].


Wow, the doc page for ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsv is rather unilluminating. It basic just say, "You did something incorrect in this BVP; but it can solve this IVP." They don't say what's wrong with the BVP, though. I would think the analysis of the problem by NDSolve[] could be more precise and informative here.

Hmm, a bug: Clear[t0, a0, qb, tinf]; DSolveChangeVariables[  Inactive[DSolve][{(w1''[t] - 2) G[w1[t]]/g[w1[t]] + (c0*k - w1[t]) + (w1'[t])^2/2 == 0, w1'[tinf] == tinf - c0 - qb, w1'[t0] == a0}, w1, t]  , w2, u,  u == Rescale[t, {tinf, t0}]  ]

To amplify @138Aspen's remark about "timetick": We can think of a differential equation problem as relating to an independent variable space (a 1D real interval in ODEs) and a dependent variable space (of dimension equal to the sum of the differential orders of the dependent variables). Ignoring events, the solving takes place in the dependent variable space. ParametricNDSolve[] extends the dependent variable space by adding dimensions for the parameters. You can't use parameters to indicate points in the independent variable space, for BCs, say. (My inference & undocumented AFAIK.)

Don't really understand the DV. It seems a reasonable Q about behavior that turns out to be undocumented. The docs even suggest it shouldn't be a problem: "Initial conditions can be specified as parameters..." It does not say this is restricted in some way. And as my first comment above points out, the error message is hopelessly unhelpful.

In ParametricNDSolveValue, use w1'[4.5] == a0 instead of w1'[t0] == a0
I guess, in boundary value settings, timetick itself can not be parametric.
Full code:
ClearAll["Global`*"];

Clear[t0, a0, qb];
c0 = 2;
tinf = 4;
tsup = 5;
k = tsup - tinf;
s = 1;
G[c_] = 1/(1 + Exp[-(c - c0*k)/s]);
g[c_] = D[G[c], c];
H[w_] = G[w]  (1 - G[w]);
h[w_] = D[H[w], w];

WR1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(w1''[t] - 2)  G[w1[t]]/
       g[w1[t]] + (c0*k - w1[t]) + (w1'[t])^2/2 == 0, 
   w1'[tinf] == tinf - c0 - qb, w1'[4.5] == a0}, 
  w1, {t, tinf, t0}, {t0, qb, a0}]

t0 = 4.5;
qb = 2;
a0 = .2;
Plot[WR1[t0, qb, a0][t], {t, tinf, t0}, PlotRange -> All]


From my point of view, ParametricNDSolveValue is just syntactic sugar. You can use below code for better encapsulation.
ClearAll["Global`*"];
c0 = 2;
tinf = 4;
tsup = 5;
k = tsup - tinf;
s = 1;
G[c_] = 1/(1 + Exp[-(c - c0*k)/s]);
g[c_] = D[G[c], c];
H[w_] = G[w]   (1 - G[w]);
h[w_] = D[H[w], w];



WR1temp[t0_, qb_, a0_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   sol = NDSolveValue[{(w1''[t] - 2)   G[w1[t]]/g[w1[t]] + (c0*k - 
          w1[t]) + (w1'[t])^2/2 == 0, w1'[tinf] == tinf - c0 - qb, 
      w1'[t0] == a0}, w1, {t, tinf, t0}];
   sol];


t0 = 4.5;
qb = 2;
a0 = .2;
WR1tempInstance = WR1temp[t0, qb, a0]
Plot[WR1tempInstance[t], {t, tinf, t0}, PlotRange -> All]


many thanks Aspen!
